# How to redirect all API requests using .htaccess, while keeping asset requests intact?

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess, angularjs, mod-rewrite

TL; DR: I would like to hit the `index-api.php` file if `api` is found in the URL, but then simply keep all other requests pointing to the `site/dist` directory as if it were the 'root' of the site.

So, I've spent way too many hours on this and trust me, I've dug through all of the resources for mod_rewrite. I guess I'm just not quite understanding and figured I'd ask on here.

What I want to do, in theory, seems simple. I'm building a single page application (Angular App) using Grunt, outputting that to a the root of a WordPress install. The WordPress install is simply serving up an API using the WordPress JSON API plugin, so I want the root of the site to hit my Grunt directory (located at `site/dist/index.html`), but all requests to `siteurl.com/api` to hit the `index.php` file and proceed normally.

Keep in mind I have other assets / images located in this `site/dist` directory, so ideally, it would be awesome if all requests to the site root would simply use this folder as the "base" of the site (e.g. a request to `siteurl.com/images/testimage.jpg` pulls from `site/dist/images/testimage.jpg`).

I feel like I'm onto something here and am surprised I couldn't find anything that directly tackles this issue.

What I've done now is renamed the `index.php` from WordPress to `index-api.php` and left it the same:

#### index-api.php:

```
<?php

define('WP_USE_THEMES', true);



/** Loads the WordPress Environment and Template */
require('./wordpress/wp-blog-header.php');
// phpInfo();
```

#### .htaccess:

```
<ifModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteRule ^api/(.*)$ index-api.php [L]
RewriteRule (.*)$ site/dist/index.html [L]

</ifModule>
```

I tried a myriad of other efforts from a few posts trying to get this working, and it seems to me like it should work fine. The funny thing is, if I comment out the last line `RewriteRule (.*)$ site/dist/index.html [L]` the api request works normally as expected, so I know I'm close.

Any suggestions?

Would appreciate anyone's help on this, it's been really confusing!

Comment: In theory, it should work, but I believe WordPress makes all requests go through it's own router page. I would consider using a `RewriteCond` for the second rule, but my knowledge about Wordpress is so limited I am unsure if that will accomplish anything: http://pastebin.com/sn9pt4VS

Comment: @Sumurai8 so, disregard WordPress for a moment. How do I point all requests to `/api/` to one file, but then have the other `site/dist` directory act as the "root" for all other requests?

Comment: Did you take a look at the pastebin?

Comment: @Sumurai8 I did, but here's the problem. With your sample, my redirection to assets which live inside that `/site/dist` directory don't show up, which makes sense because all requests are being pushed to that `index.html` file. I guess I'm more curious if I can simply have all requests 'think' that the `/site/dist` is the site root, and thus a request to `images/test.jpg` would actually pull from `/site/dist/images/test.jpg`. Does this make sense? Is this even possible?

Comment: I've added an answer with what I think you want to have. You might need to exclude `/index.php` or whatever wordpress uses in the last rule too.

Answer (score 3):

In the first place you'll need to make sure that requests made to `/index-api.php` are not matched and rewritten by the second rule. In the second rule you can use `$1`. `$1` will be replaced with whatever was matched in the first capture group. We'll also need to make sure that the second rule will not match what it rewrites, or we'll end up with an infinite loop and an internal error.

You can use the `$1` in the first rule too, as I show below:

```
RewriteRule ^api/(.*)$ index-api.php?url=$1 [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/site/dist/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/index-api\.php
RewriteRule (.*)$ site/dist/$1 [L]
```

I recommend reading [the documentation](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html) of mod_rewrite to get a better understanding how you can use it and what things you have at your disposal while rewriting url's.