# What is the proper setup of an .htaccess file for headless WordPress and React site

Tags: reactjs, wordpress, .htaccess, wp-api

I have a Wordpress site with a headless React frontend. With the default .htaccess file that Wordpress puts up on install, the site was not correctly handling requests to any page other than the root. Those requests ignored React altogether. I modified the .htaccess to point all requests to the index.html file like the following...

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.html$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.html [L]
</IfModule>
```

This loads the React site just fine on all requests, but it's also failing on any api request to either wp-json or more importantly graphql. This means the page loads, but the content is essentially absent. How can I set up the .htaccess file to allow requests to those api endpoints on top of allowing the initial requests going to the index.html?

Comment: Please do mention path of your .htaccess file and your index.html file? Are they residing in same path?

Comment: @RavinderSingh13 same directory yes.

Comment: "any api request to either wp-json or more importantly graphql." - what is the specific format of these URLs?

Comment: @MrWhite not really sure what you mean by format. Graphql uses POST requests exclusively and the endpoint is https://mydomaindotcom/graphql. I believe that if all requests going to */graphql are processed by `index.php` and all other requests are handled by index.html the problem might be solved, but I'm not at all sure how to write that in the htaccess file.

Comment: By "format" I mean the URL(s) that you are requesting. ie. The endpoints for your (WordPress) API. If there are multiple URLs, do they following a specific "format", `/graphql/<something>`? Or is it literally just `/graphql`?

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be working so far...

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^graphql(.*)$ index.php?url=$1 [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.html [L]
</IfModule>
```

Stole part of this from this answer...
[How to redirect all API requests using .htaccess, while keeping asset requests intact?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20170861/how-to-redirect-all-api-requests-using-htaccess-while-keeping-asset-requests-i)

I'm not sure I need that `url=$1` part since I'm not using it elsewhere, but I'm not that good at regex and at least the request are getting handled correctly.

Comment: That rule rewrites requests for `/graphql<anything>` and captures the `<anything>` part (passing this as the value to the `url` parameter). Is that the intention? Standard WordPress doesn't use a `url` parameter.